# JasperReport and Spring compatibility

Tags: spring, jasper-reports

I have integrated JasperReport version: 5.0.2 on a spring based project and it works fine.
If I want to increase the version after 5.0.2 I am getting errors in server and cannot start

AFter upgrading the version I receive the error below:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in
>   com.nimbussoft.erp.configuration.JpaConfiguration

The dependency for the jasper is:

> ```
>         <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
>         <version>6.2.1</version>
>         </dependency>
> ```

Is there anything I need to be aware of which has to be added in order versions after 5.0.2 to work fine with spring?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check that you have remove old version of Jasperreports in your project (in also all your subproject). If towo bean use the same name it can be a cause of BeanCreationException. You can check that also by activating log at debug level to see all bean creation trace and verify if the bean has already been present.

Comment: yes. The older versions are removed and there is no bean with same names. What's strange, I only change the jasper version number and some how after version 5.0.2 it doesn't seem to be working. prior versions work fine